# Stream oriented IO vs Block Oriented IO

Tags: java, io, nio

Java has stream oriented IO(java.io.*) and Block oriented IO(java.nio.*). How does block oriented IO improve the performance of IO?

Comment: I wouldn't describe NIO as 'block-oriented'.

Comment: @EJP- Can you explain that in a bit more detail? I'm reading this article and they clearly call it block oriented .. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-nio/section2.html

Comment: Late to the party, but *block* here means a body of data, an array or bytes,... not the blocking behaviour. Some other literature use the term "buffer oriented" instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primarily by reducing the need for copying. Since the stream-oriented APIs have to move everything into managed Java variables, the system has to copy all of the data you deal with. When you use the NIO libraries, Java can directly map in the OS I/O pages without having to make copies (and deal with allocation and garbage collection).

Answer (score 6):

The **stream-based I/O** uses streams to transfer data between a data source/sink and a Java program. The Java program reads from or writes to a stream a byte at a time. This approach to performing I/O operations is slow. The New Input/Ouput (NIO) solves the slow speed problem in the older stream-based I/O.

[image]

In **NIO**, you deal with **channels** and **buffers** for I/O operations.

A channel is like a stream. It represents a connection between a data source/sink and a Java program for data transfer.

[image]

There is one difference between a channel and a stream.

- A stream can be used for **one-way** data transfer. That is, an input
  stream can only transfer data from a data source to a Java program;
  an output stream can only transfer data from a Java program to a data
  sink.
- However, a channel provides a **two-way** data transfer facility.

You can use a channel to read data as well as to write data. You can obtain a read-only channel, a write-only channel, or a read-write channel depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

From the **[Source](https://blogs.oracle.com/slc/entry/javanio_vs_javaio)**:-

> **IO vs. NIO**
>
> NIO construction makes I/O faster than traditional I/O. In a program
> where the I/O operations constitute a significant amount of the
> processing, expect to see some difference. For example if an
> application has to copy files or transfer bytes using sockets, using
> Nio is possible to obtain a faster performance because it is closer to
> the OS than the I/O API. Increasing the byte size, the difference
> becomes  more appreciable. Nio also provides other features not in io
> API, for streaming operations. However, it is not possible to
> substitute IO with NIO because NIO API adds functionalities to the
> java.io. NIO extends the native IO API introducing new possibilities
> for the developer to manipulate stream data in a powerful way.

Comment: It doesnt explain what extra stuff stream oriented IO does that reduces the performance.

Comment: It says Streams are generally, but not necessarily, slower than block devices, and are often the source of intermittent input. Most operating systems allow streams to be placed into non-blocking mode, which permits a process to check if input is available on the stream, without getting stuck if none is available at a given moment.

Comment: @ChanderShivdasani:- Although Chyslis has explained very clearly that **stream-oriented APIs have to move everything into managed Java variables, the system has to copy all of the data you deal with.**

Comment: Read your answer before his :)

Comment: @ChanderShivdasani:- Not an issue!!! He has explained the whole story in a short form.:)

Comment: @ChanderShivdasani:- I would recommend you to read the link which I have added in my answer. It is interesting!!!