# Why are NIO FileChannels created from InputStream/OutputStream

Tags: java, io, nio

FileChannel in Java implements both ReadableByteChannel and WritableByteChannel, which makes them bi-directional.

**Question**:

To create a FileChannel, I need FileInputStream(for reading) and FileOutputStream(for writing). Doesnt that defeat the purpose of making them bi-directional, since I need to instantiate both the streams?

**Follow up Question:**

I've seen references at many places stating that java.io is stream oriented, and java.nio is block oriented([Here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-nio/)). Then why are they instantiated through InputStream and OutputStream? Is the block oriented notion, just an abstraction over Streams?

Comment: You _can_ get them through `InputStream` and `OutputStream`, and some stream implementations will provide optimized channels specialized for block-oriented IO, and some stream implementations will just use a simplistic default built on top of the stream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*To create a FileChannel, I need FileInputStream(for reading) and FileOutputStream(for writing).*

You don't. You can use [`FileChannel.open(Path, OpenOption...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29)

```
Path path = ...;
FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(path, options)
channel.read(byteBuffer);
channel.write(byteBuffer);
```

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677258/stream-oriented-io-vs-block-oriented-io) for an answer to your follow up question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked the code for FileInputStream.java and internally, it calls FileChannel.open() to create a FileChannel.